# Driver download without virus

Tags: drivers

I have a system with asustek p5gv-tmx motherboard. The previous sys admin lost the driver cd. Where can i find the Ethernet drivers for that board? The generic intel driver is not working.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a Realtek RTL8100C on that board, so check out the [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=6&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3) driver site.
UPDATE: The TMX is a surplus OEM mother board, not supported by ASUS. It has a Realtek RTL8110S-32 card, and the drivers are found [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/searchView.aspx?keyword=RTL8110S-32).

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to know if there is a site which hosts drivers for all kind of mother board. Asus is the worst i could find. Motherboard drivers for HP PCs are easily downloaded from their site. so half my PCs are up n running.

Comment: I think it will be hard to find a generic all-in-one-virus-free-and-without-annoying-ads download site for all kinds of mother boards.
It is probably easier to find out where to find the specific drivers (like the Realtek Ethernet interface). What drivers are you missing (and for what OS)?

Comment: Thanks again. I got the driver from realtek and most of the systems are now connected. Now i have a doubt. How did you find out that it had a realtek card? If i had known that i would 've searched realtek site before asking the question. Is there a tool or you answered out of your long experience? The system information for windows tool showed it as just intel <some number> in one p[lace and unknown ethernet in another place.

Comment: ASUS has a specification sheet for P5GV-MX at http://www.asus.com/Product.aspx?P_ID=dIBvHjLhvaOrmJzA&content=specifications, but I found now that the TMX and the MX are a little different. According to http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=1&model=P5GV-MX&id=20080709152936328&page=1&SLanguage=en-us the TMX is a OEM product, and following to the Russian site I see that it sports a Realtek RTL8110S-32 chip... I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that generally you have to decide:

- trusted source **OR**
- easy to navigate

**Trusted Source**:

The only trusted source is IMHO the manufacturer/vendor - unfortunately nobody really cares about signed code (that is not necessarily the Windows Signature). All the other options aren't verifiable and thus aren't trustworthy.

The best bet for a generic and somewhat trustworthy is, if you have money to spend, to get a proper support contract from your vendor to keep you updated about the stuff you need.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the manufacturer when possible...and 99% of the time I find what I am looking for.  For the other 1% of the time I look on driverguide.com.  They have been around forever.  Thier site requires registration and is very 'busy' looking.  Even their simple search is a bit complicated.  They offer free* driver download and will send you a CD for a fee.

- I havent used them recently and assume they are still free